# printing a string from an array

Tags: java

Write a static method named listCountriesOfOrigin, to be added to the Bowl class, which is passed an array of Bowl objects, and prints to the console in a column the country of origin of each of Bowl objects in the array.

This is my code but is not right and the only compilation errors I am getting is "The system has detected compilation errors." So it is not helping me much. Am i on the right path?

```
public static String listCountriesOfOrigin (Bowl[] bowls) {
  for(int i = 0; i < Bowl.length; i++) {
    String origin = bowls[i].getOrigin();
    return origin;
  }
}
```

(.getOrigin) is already a declared method that returns the origins of the objects from the array.

Comment: `bowls.length` not `Bowl.length`

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < Bowl.length; i++) // `Bowl` is the object name
```

shouldn't this be

```
for(int i = 0; i < bowls.length; i++) // bowls is the name of the array of Bowl objects passed to your method.
```

Also there should not be a `return` statement inside your `for`. According to your requirements, your method should `print` those values on the console.

Hence, make your method return `void` and instead of the `return` in the `for` loop, have a `System.out.println(origin);`

Comment: It may not be a good coding practice to have a return statement inside for loop, but how will it cause compilation error ?

Comment: @aiuna - After fixing all this, pls tell, what's the actual compilation error, as from the code snippet you've posted, there doesn't seem to be 1.

Comment: Excellent, just followed what you said and worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Setting to void and then just using the SOP statement fixed it.

Comment: @aiuna - The problem was indeed the `return` in `for`. Good that's its fixed now.